# c++/cli Control loop with assumption of control type

Tags: loops, user-controls, c++-cli

I would like to access all of my user controls within the `Controls` group. I am using the following loop:

```
std::vector<LaminaClass> Laminae;

for each(Control ^E in Controls)
{
    if (E->GetType() == ClassLibrary1::Lamina_Input1::typeid)
    {
        // Create a new lamina class object by copying the current lamina control handle
        LaminaClass newLam(E);

        // Put the lamina in the appropriate location in the Laminae vector:
        Laminae.push_back(newLam);
    }
}
```

The problem is, even though I filtered the controls with an `if` statement, I still can't assume the control `E` is of the type `ClassLibrary1::Lamina_Input1` meaning I can't do anything that is specific to that control type to/with it. I can do general control things but not anything that is unique to `Lamina_Input1` controls.

I've also tried this:

```
std::vector<LaminaClass> Laminae;

    // For each lamina control in the group of controls:
for each(ClassLibrary1::Lamina_Input1 ^LamContr in Controls)
{
    // Create a new lamina class object by copying the current lamina control handel
    LaminaClass newLam(LamContr);

    // Put the lamina in the appropriate location in the Laminae vector:
    Laminae.push_back(newLam);
}
```

In this case, I get the following error:
[image: Run-time Error]

In the debugger:
[image: Debugger]

I've been stuck on this for a while now. I've put in a lot of time trying to look up the answer but have been unsuccessful (likely due to my inability to accurately describe the problem in a concise manner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

Are you looking for a cast to the proper type?

```
LaminaClass newLam(dynamic_cast<Lamina_Input1^>(E));
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Even if you check that `E` is the type you expect, that doesn't change the type of `E`, you still have to cast it.

Specifying a subclass in a `for each` loop is valid, but it will do a `static_cast` of each object in the list to that type, which as you've found, will throw an exception if the cast isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this in C++/CLI is to take advantage of contextual conversion to `bool`, that is, using a handle type as a conditional expression automatically becomes a comparison to `nullptr`.

For example:

```
for each(Control ^E in Controls)
{
    if (auto LI = dynamic_cast<ClassLibrary1::Lamina_Input1^>(E))
    {
        LaminaClass newLam(LI);

        // ...
    }
}
```

For those familiar with C#, this is equivalent to using the `as` keyword, e.g.

```
foreach (Control E in Controls)
{
    var LI = E as Lamina_Input;
    if (LI != null)
    {
        new LaminaClass(LI) // ...
    }
}
```

except that the scope is only the `if` statement itself.  In C# 7 there's finally a true equivalent:

```
foreach (Control E in Controls)
{
    if (E is Lamina_Input LI)
    {
        new LaminaClass(LI) // ...
    }
}
```